# Get all item in cart using quote id Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, quote, quoteitem

Is there a way to load all items in cart, only using quote entity_id from quote table in magento 2 database?

Comment: you want the query or the code that retrieves them?

Comment: @Marius i don't want to load it from raw query, i need to load it from collection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want to get that in a class.
If not, you should.

Let's say the class name is `Vendor\Module\Model\QuoteItems`. 
It should look like this:

```
<?php 
namespace  Vendor\Module\Model;

class QuoteItems
{
    protected $quoteRepository;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    )
    {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }
    public function getQuoteItems($quoteId)
    {
         try {
             $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($quoteId);
             $items = $quote->getAllItems();
             return $items;
         } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
             return [];
         }
    }
}
```

then you can use your class to retrieve the items with the method `getQuoteItems`.
Or you can use the code inside the method directly, just by injecting an instance of the quote repository in your class.

Comment: it returns empty array